# How to remove footer from file while reading file in spark scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I am trying to remove footer from file while reading file. is there any option like "footer" = "true".

Comment: How does the file looks like?

Answer (score 0):

The best approach will be to use Unix to remove footer from file

```
sed -i '$ d' foo.txt
```

If you want to do it spark way 
You can first create dataframe then convert  it into rdd and remove the last row from DF

lets say df is your dataframe after file read

```
val cnt= df.count();
val rdd = dataframe.rdd  // convert df to rdd

//-- RDD without footer
val rddWithoutfoot = rdd.zipWithIndex().filter(x => x._2 < cnt )
                            .map (x => x._1)

// Dataframe without  footer
val dfWithoutfoot = spark.createDataFrame(rddWithoutFoot , df.schema)
```

Comment: I have tried it but it is giving me Error
org.apache.spark.SparkException: Task not serializable.

Comment: can u tell me at which step it is giving me error rddWithoutfoot  or dfWithoutfoot